# Using object.keys(arguments).length VS arguments.length

Tags: javascript, performance, arguments, javascript-objects

I'm new to JS and trying to understand something I read in a couple of places:

While trying to get the number of arguments received to a function, there was use of
`Object.keys(arguments).length`. However, as far as I could find, there isn't any benefit for this and the shorter way would be to just use `arguments.length`

This is because `arguments` holds the `.length` property.
([MDN doc - The arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments))

Is there somethings I'm missing?
Are there situations where using `object.keys()` is preferred on terms of performance or safety?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arguments` is an "exotic object" which is "array-like" - it has numeric properties and `.length`. Using `Object.keys` with it makes as much sense as `Object.keys(someArray)`, that is, none.

In new code it's better to avoid `arguments` altogether because of its shady features, like invisible mutation of argument variables. Example:

```js
function someFunctionThatMutatesArray(a) {
    a[0] = 'hey'
}

function func(xyz) {
    someFunctionThatMutatesArray(arguments)
    console.log(xyz) // surprise
}

func(100)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you point me to where I could find some data regarding arguments's "invisible mutation of argument variables" and other problematic features? I couldn't find anything...
Also, What would you recommend using instead of ```arguments``` for new code?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys(arguments).length` Would also work if `arguments` is an object:

```js
let arguments = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

console.log('Array', Object.keys(arguments).length);

arguments = { 1: 'foo', 2: 'bar', 3: 'baz' }

console.log('Object', Object.keys(arguments).length);
```

That said, if the input value is known to be an array (which `arguments` is), it's absolutely unecessary to use `Object.keys`.

Comment: @VLAZ: That assumes we're talking about a function's `arguments`, and not some variable someone declared. Which would be correct in this case, but still makes the explanation useful.

Comment: That still doesn't mean I shouldn't explain why `Object.keys` could have been used there...

Comment: As VLAZ mentioned, my question refers to the arguments reserved word (arguments passed to the function), and as I understand from the doc, it's an array-like object so it will always be an array. @VLAZ

@Cerbrus - I've edited my question to ```Object```. Thanks!


So... for my question, Is there any a reason to use the ```Object.keys()```?
I'm sorry, but I can't mark this as the answer as I feel it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `Object.keys(arguments).length` to get the count of the passed in arguments for a function. The value is always going to be identical to `arguments.length`, so it is superfluous at best.

Since you have [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) tag, I would add that `Object.keys().length` is likely to be slower. *However*, it is also unlikely to have much of an impact overall.

```js
function test() {
  const keysLength = Object.keys(arguments).length;
  const argsLength = arguments.length;
  console.log( `keys: [${keysLength}] arguments: [${argsLength}] equal: [${keysLength === argsLength}]` );
}

test();
test(1);
test(1, 2);
test(1, 2, null);
test(1, 2, undefined, 4);
test(1, 2, undefined, 4, ["a", "b", "c"]);
test({foo: "hello", bar: "world"});
test({foo: "hello", bar: "world"});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and example! I've chosen georg's answer, as I feel it's more specific regarding the ```arguments``` reserved word. I did upvote your answer since I believe it has important data. Thanks